# GA4 Event Showing Up in DeBug But Not Tracked in Conversions

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I've waited more than 48 hours for the event to show up and just changed reporting identity to 'Device-based', to no luck. The created event, also marked as a conversion, is 'ScheduleCallSubmit'. It doesn't show up in the listed events in 'Events', and isn't tracked in 'Conversions', but 'Debug View' tracks it as it should.

Any suggestions on how I could get GA4 to track it? I've also created a pageview event in GTM 48+ hours ago that fires in the Tag Assistant for the same pageview as 'ScheduleCallSubmit', but doesn't appear in GA4's 'Events' list at all.

I was expecting for a page_view of the 'Thank-You' page once someone books a call on the website to be tracked as an event and conversion (named ScheduleCallSubmit), but it's not being tracked in GA4 as either, except in Debug View.

Comment: Did you check your filter settings, if the property has internal traffic filter enabled?

Comment: have you installed the GTM or GTAG n the front-end side?
you should provide your settings as well so we could help more